# Shifting rows of matrices depending on some other data

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization, apply, mapply

I'm sorry for repeating a question about the *apply functions, but I cannot get my code to work with the material that I found so far. I have a matrix (stored in a large data frame) and I want to shift the rows of this matrix by a certain amount (to the left). The amount by which I want to shift is different for each row and is stored in another column of the same data frame. The following code should illustrate what I am aiming for

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(15),ncol=5,nrow=3);
sv <- c(1,4,2);

mat;

shift <- function(x,shift){c(x[(1+max(0,shift)):length(x)],rep(0,max(0,shift)))}

for(i in 1:nrow(mat)){mat[i,] <-  shift(mat[i,],sv[i])}

mat;
```

But this runs incredibly slow on my 300000x201 matrix, so how could I vectorize this (using some of *apply commands)?

Comment: If your variables share the same class, consider using matrix instead of data.frame, it will be much faster. Other thing, avoiding functions and parameters (shift) having the same name is often a good idea.

Comment: ok, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working on larger chunks will speedup things

```
n.col <- ncol(mat)
for(i in unique(sv)){
  selection <- which(sv == i)
  mat[selection, 1:(n.col - i + 1)] <- mat[selection, i:n.col]
  mat[selection, (n.col - i + 1):n.col] <- 0
}
```

Comment: Nice solution ! 2nd line of the loop should'nt be:   mat4[selection, 1:(n.col - i)] <- mat4[selection, (i+1):n.col]  ?